# Oracle Alternative to EXISTS EXCEPT

Tags: oracle, minus

I wonder if there is an equally elegant solution for Oracle for the problem posted and answered here:

[Comparing Columns that can contain NULLS - is there a more elegant way?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15190/comparing-columns-that-can-contain-nulls-is-there-a-more-elegant-way)

I can't get this solution (the one which was accepted) to work in Oracle environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be the Oracle equivalent to the accepted answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM a a1 
  JOIN b b1 
    ON a1.id = b1.id 
   AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM a a2 where a2.id = a1.id
              MINUS 
              SELECT * FROM b b2 where b2.id = b1.id);
```

I have never seen a `select a.*` before (i.e. a `select` without a `FROM` clause using an alias instead of constant values) but I assume it maps to a co-related subquery

Note that onedaywhen's answer would work as well in Oracle (when replacing `except` with `minus`):

```
WITH a_minus_b AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM A
  minus 
  SELECT *
  FROM B
)
SELECT * 
FROM a_minus_b T 
   JOIN B ON T.ID = B.ID;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f369/1

---

Just for completeness: in standard SQL this could be written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM a 
  JOIN b 
    ON a.id = b.id 
where (a.string, a.dt, a.b, a.num) is distinct from (b.string, b.dt, b.b, b.num);
```

which is e.g. supported by Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b431b/1